# mysql equation inside where clause and between

Tags: mysql

I need to compute some math equation and check if its within  a range stored in another table.something like the below table:

```
+--------------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
| no    | TOTAL | Out Of  |  grad   | point      |
+--------------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
| 1000  | 833   |  1100   |   A     |     12     |
+--------------+-------+--------+-------+--------+
```

av tried to achieve it with the following

**query**

```
SELECT no,sum(score) as TOTAL,(100*count(scores.code)) as "Out Of",
       grad, point 
from scores,gradings 
where (no=1000) and (exam=1) 
and ((sum(score)/(100*count(exams_scores.subject_code))*100) 
  between gradings.range_begin and gradings.range_end)
;
```

**gradings Table**

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| id   | range_begin  | range_end |  grad  | point  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1    |  70          |  80       |  A     | 12     |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2    |   60         |  70       | B      | 11     |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

**scores table**

```
+---------------------------------------+
| no      |  exam   |  code    | score  |
+---------------------------------------+
|1000     |   1     | 121      | 70     |
+---------------------------------------+
|1000     |    1    | 231      | 80     |
+---------------------------------------+
|1001     |     1   | 121      |  56    |
+---------------------------------------+
|1001     |    1    |  231     |  85    |
+---------------------------------------+
```

i am getting

**error message**

```
Mysql ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

i think the error comes from the equation with the between clause but i dont know how to solve it..

Can anyone help ?

Comment: filters on aggregate expressions ( sum/count etc ) need to be made in `having` clause, not the where clause. also you will need to group by your non-aggregate fields

Comment: The logic you are trying to apply doesn't make sense.  Putting the `sum()` in the `where` clause is the immediate problem, but you need to better explain your logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add up the exam scores per student no to get the totals:

```
SELECT `no`, SUM(score) AS total, 100*COUNT(`code`) AS outof
FROM scores
WHERE exam=1
GROUP BY `no`
```

Then, join the result of that query to the gradings:

```
SELECT s.`no`, s.total, s.outof, g.grad, g.point
FROM (
    SELECT `no`, SUM(score) AS total, 100*COUNT(`code`) AS outof
    FROM scores
    WHERE exam=1
    GROUP BY `no`
) s
JOIN gradings g ON s.total/s.outof*100 BETWEEN g.range_begin AND g.range_end
WHERE s.`no`=1000;
```